# Error adding service reference

Tags: c#, web-services

So I’m trying to add a service reference in WebForms 4.5 project.

I keep getting a same error message:

> The configuration for the service reference could not be added due to
>   the following error: An error occurred creating the configuration
>   section handler for system.ServiceModel/bindings: AssemblyResolveEvent
>   handlers cannot return Assemblies loaded for reflexion only.

You can test this service to add : http://beeyepoll.azurewebsites.net/apis/PollsService.asmx

It works in every project, except this one :(

Comment: are you already tried to clean <system.serviceModel> in web.config?

Comment: Yep, tried even to delete all content of web.config. Same message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error updating service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760892/error-updating-service-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up creating separate DLL project and importing service reference there. Still don`t know why it did not work directly in the main project.