# Update service reference error "interface not supported"

Tags: wcf, service, reference

I added a field to a table in the SQL Server database of a web site.
The web site works well.

Now I need to update the service reference of a WCF utility that communicates with the website.
In Solution Explorer (Visual Studio 2019) I go in the "Service references" of the project, there is only ONE element, I right-click over, appears the context menu, I select "Update ..." and I obtain an error: "Interface not supported" with no explanations.
And the WCF application of course fails communicating with the web site.

I'm completely ignorant abot WCF, all the code was written by another developer now "gone".

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You updated the fields in the database, but did you use the table in the wcf code? If you do, you need to make changes accordingly. When you are done, right-click the service reference you want to update in the Connect Service options and click Update Service Reference.

If this update doesn't work, you may refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760892/error-updating-service-reference) to cut out the service. Model section of web.config and update the Service reference.

If all else fails, [remove the service reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2022) and add it again. Of course, back up your code when you do this.

Comment: Can you explain "but did you use the table in the wcf code? If you do, you need to make changes accordingly". I don't understand what you mean.  The code uses the changed table, for this reason I need to update the edmx file of the service reference, because currently the communcation fails due to the database change.

Comment: If I remove the service reference, then I need to add it again ... I know the URL, something like "www.myurl.it" (is the url of the website where i changed the database table).
Should I use this URL exactly "www.myurl.it" or do I need something different?

Comment: What I mean is that if you use this new field in your wcf code, you need to update your code accordingly, and then update your service reference. If you used this URL before, use it to add the service reference after removing it.